# How to turn string indices into integers

Tags: python, json, alpha-vantage

```
import requests

API_KEY = 'demo'
r = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=' + API_KEY)
if (r.status_code == 200):
    result = r.json()
    dataForAllDays = 'TIME_SERIES_DAILY'
    dataForSingleDate = '2020-08-14'
    print (dataForSingleDate['1. open'])
    print (dataForSingleDate['2. high'])
    print (dataForSingleDate['3. low'])
    print (dataForSingleDate['4. close'])
    print (dataForSingleDate['5. volume'])

else:
    print("None")
```

I followed a tutorial on Youtube and when I tried to run my program, I got a typeerror message. I'm not sure why I got it and have tried to fix it.

Comment: please add your full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

look at these lines, I assume you are trying to slice the string `dataForSingleDate`:

```
    print (dataForSingleDate['1. open'])
    print (dataForSingleDate['2. high'])
    print (dataForSingleDate['3. low'])
    print (dataForSingleDate['4. close'])
    print (dataForSingleDate['5. volume'])
```

In your program `dataForSingleDate` is `string` and if you are trying to slice the `string` you will have to use `integer` `index` but here you are using `string` hence your program is throwing the `TypeError`. `string` slicing is something like below:

```
dataForSingleDate[1]
dataForSingleDate[2]
```

you can go through this article to know more about `slice` https://www.journaldev.com/23584/python-slice-string

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

API_KEY = 'demo'
r = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=' + API_KEY)
if (r.status_code == 200):
    result = r.json()
    dataForAllDays = result['Time Series (Daily)']
    dataForSingleDate = dataForAllDays['2020-08-17']
    print (dataForSingleDate['1. open'])
    print (dataForSingleDate['2. high'])
    print (dataForSingleDate['3. low'])
    print (dataForSingleDate['4. close'])
    print (dataForSingleDate['5. volume'])

else:
    print("None")
```

The "dataForAllDays" string has to be looked up in the "result" variable.
This is key:value indexing.

The data for a single day is then directly available to be looked up once you retrieve the data for all days

Another way to see it is let's say you have a data dict,

```
data = {"today":{"noon":12, "midnight":0}}
today = data["today"]
noon = today["noon"]
```

You can also do everything in one go..

```
noon = data["today"]["noon"]
```

Comment: I'm scraping the data from a site and the format is '1. open' : '2. open' :. So wouldn't I have to follow the same format as the site?

Comment: Yes, you have to follow same format as given in the site. The later example was to explain how to index a dictionary. Did you try the modified code above? I modified to give the desired result.